# Export a pre calculated column from sql

Tags: sql, excel

I want to export a file from sql server as an excel file.

But i don't know how to export a column already have a calculated formula.

For exemple :

```
ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC
   5           columna+columnb
```

NB :
The column b is empty, i'll fill the column after i export the file from sql.

Comment: That's not going to work. SQL's syntax for expressions doesn't match Excel's. When exporting data, you can only get the calculated value of the column, not its formula, and even if you could Excel wouldn't accept it (except in really trivial cases like `A + B`, where the syntax does happen to coincide), and even if Excel *did* accept it you can't import text as if it were a formula. You'll have to check the definitions of computed columns beforehand and define them in your sheets, and exclude them from the export.

Comment: Alternatively, put the text formula in the query (`'A + B' AS Formula`) as text and convert it later. This way you at least keep the formula and the data together. You still can't fully automatically turn computed columns into formulas, though.